# Clear Jinja Output on Refresh

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm new so I'm not sure what to do. I have a webpage that uses Flask with Jinja templates that takes in a user text via GET and POST, and passes it to a scaler.save, saves the result as 'prediction' and 'probability'. Depending on if the prediction is 1 or 0, it'll display a different 'text' or 'percent' and use redirect to pass it to the index page.

My issue is that when the page is refreshed or if someone goes to another part of the website and comes back to the index, the index still shows the  {{ text }} and {{ percent }} values. I would like those values to be cleared out if page is reloaded. Like, showing them at first when the form is submitted but then cleared out on a new reload. I have the page hosted on Heroku and it still displays another user's {{ text }} and {{ percent }} and it should be cleared out if a new person is on it and loads it.

I've included the code in the Flask below and HTML. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", text=text, percent=percent)


@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        my_input = request.form.to_dict()
        my_input_array = pd.Series(my_input["input text"])
        my_input_array2= my_input["input text"]

        print(my_input_array)

        prediction = scaler.predict(my_input_array)
        probability= scaler.predict_proba(my_input_array)
        trumpper= "{:.2%}".format(probability[0][0])
        hilper= "{:.2%}".format(probability[0][1])


        if prediction == 0:
            
            text= my_input_array2
            percent= trumpper

        elif prediction == 1:
            
            text= my_input_array2
            percent= hilper
        
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

This is the HTML:

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}" method="post">
  <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" name="input text" placeholder="input text here" required="required" rows="3" </textarea>
  <!--<input type="text" textarea class="form-control" name="input text" placeholder="input text" required="required" rows="3"></textarea> -->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Submit text </button>
</form>

<br> {% if value %}
<div class="card text-white bg-secondary mb-3" style="max-width: 1000px;">


  <div class="card-header">
    <h3>Your text: <i>"{{ text }}" </i></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h3 class="card-title">MY PREDICTION IS:
      <i><b> {{ percent }}  {{ value }} </b></i>
      <br>
    </h3>

  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You are using global variables to store the prediction results?

Comment: It's interesting you ask that question. I was before, but I removed that. But the Jinja output on the page still displays the text and percent when refreshing. Even did CTRL+ F5 and it still does...